# Making part of a placeholder/value in textInput italics in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app that allows the user to customise a graph. I need part of the y axis label to be in italics (not the entire sentence), but have not been able to achieve the desired output. This is an example app.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Customizable Plot Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("y_label", "Enter Y-axis Label", value = "Value - make this word **italics**"),
      actionButton("update_plot", "Update Plot")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("custom_plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Reactive expression to generate plot based on user input
  plot_data <- reactive({
    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(y = input$y_label) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
  
  # Render plot when the user clicks the 'Update Plot' button
  output$custom_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$update_plot)  # Ensure plot updates on button click
    plot_data()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the word to be made italics in the html input field or in the ggplot graphic object?

Comment: @r2evans Just in the ggplot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ggtext package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtext/vignettes/theme_elements.html) which allows to italicize a part of an axis title using the Markdown syntax, i.e. enclosing this part between asterisks - see the above link for more info.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Customizable Plot Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        "y_label", "Enter Y-axis Label", 
        value = "Value - make this word *italics*"
      ),
      actionButton("update_plot", "Update Plot")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("custom_plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Reactive expression to generate plot based on user input
  plot_data <- reactive({
    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(y = input$y_label) +
      theme(
        axis.title.y = element_markdown()
      )
  })
  
  # Render plot when the user clicks the 'Update Plot' button
  output$custom_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot_data()
  }) |> bindEvent(input$update_plot)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```